# how to retrieve data from mysql in nested Recyclerview like Playstore

Tags: android, mysql

[image]

[image]

Here is my horizantal recyclerview image.
I retrieved the data from mysql but how to show different data in every recyclerview.

Comment: What have you tried so far to debug the problem?

Comment: In Adapter change  instance of inflate(R.layout.grid,parent,null); to inflate(R.layout.grid,parent,false);

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to update the UI from a Thread that is a callback for the Firebase response.
You should call the method notifyDataSetChanged(); from the UI Thread.

Try this:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         blogPostRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```